# NextJS how to use the useEffect hook for detecting classes on page change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my `nextjs`-app I have a `Navbar`-component, where I use the `useEffect`-hook to check, if the `<body>`-tag contains a class:

Navbar.tsx:

```
const Navbar = () => {
   
   const router = useRouter()

   const [fullWidthBackground, setFullWidthBackground] = useState(false)

   useEffect(() => {
      const isFullWidth = document.body.classList.contains('full-width-hero')
      if (isFullWidth) {
        setFullWidthBackground(true)
      } else {
        setFullWidthBackground(false)
      }
   }, [fullWidthBackground])

}
```

So far, this seems to be working, BUT when I'm on a route/page that has the `full-width-hero`-class and them navigate to the `/`-route (pages -> index.tsx),which does NOT have the `full-width-hero`-class, the `isFullWidth` still returns true - so what is going on here?

Can someone help me out

Comment: I would question your approach here, as you are effectively using the `classList` on `<body>` to store a stateful value that you then observe. How is the 'full-width-hero' class being applied to your body? Are you using state somewhere else in the application to conditionally apply it? If so, can you pass through *that* state into NavBar?